# Homepage for Google Chrome 37

Tags: google-chrome, cmd.exe

I'm a sysadmin for a corporate call center with 200+ XP and 7 workstations.

Previous to Chrome version 37, I could configure Chrome for new workstations by copying a network "seed" folder containing the Chrome settings (bookmarks, homepage, preferences) via batch file to the Google "Default" folder, for both XP and 7.

With the update to Chrome 37, however, I've observed that copying my network-stored seed folder to new workstations fails to copy over the homepage, whereas the other settings from the preferences file (as well as the bookmarks) do load onto the new workstations successfully.

I've tested the possibility that it was simply an incompatibility between my old Chrome 36 seed and Chrome 37, but recreating the seed using Chrome 37 also failed to copy over the homepage.

For XP, the folder I'm copying my seed to is

```
%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
```

For 7, the folder I'm copying my seed to is:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Does anyone have any insight as to how I can automatically set Chrome 37 to keep the homepage for new profiles as well as my other settings? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to Google Chrome now putting the Homepage and Search-engine preferences in a new file called Secure Preferences.

It is hash protected by a lattice based hash called SWIFFT. You can revert it and create your own by doing a fast Fourier transform on it, find the point-wise product of the range when you interpret the extension id as a multiple-precision integer.

If you try to change the values that are not hashed, then Chrome will revert back to default settings.